# Needing to release dhclient every startup

Tags: wireless, internet, dhclient

Every startup I need to run

```
dhclient -r wlp4s0
dhclient wlp4s0
```

To get my wifi to work properly. Otherwise my wifi is connected but does not stream data. I am wondering what is going on exactly and also any fix so I dont need to do this every time I reboot.
Thanks!

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit] as this is a Q&A site, not a general forum, so things work differently here.

Comment: Totally agree with above commenter. In the meantime you could setup a simple bash script to run those two commands at startup or login.